I can't configure a swagger in java spring
I'm trying to implement a swagger on my java spring back end application. After following several tutorials, here's the result I'm getting:
SwaggerConfig :
package com.covoit.covoitbackend.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import springfox.documentation.builders.ApiInfoBuilder;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo;
import springfox.documentation.service.Contact;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class SwaggerConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select()`

                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.covoit.covoitbackend.RestService"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.regex("/.*"))
                .build().apiInfo(apiInfoMetaData());
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfoMetaData() {

        return new ApiInfoBuilder().title("Web Service covoit")
                .description("API Endpoint in persistence DB Covoit")
                .contact(new Contact("Dev-Team", "https://www.dev-team.com/", "dev-team@gmail.com"))
                .license("Apache 2.0")
                .licenseUrl("http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html")
                .version("1.0.0")
                .build();
    }

}

And pom.xml :
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

But i have error when i go in url : http://localhost:9090/swagger-ui/index.html
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Sun Apr 28 17:50:18 CEST 2024
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No endpoint GET /v3/api-docs.
org.springframework.web.servlet.NoHandlerFoundException: No endpoint GET /v3/api-docs.
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.noHandlerFound(DispatcherServlet.java:1304)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903)
at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1570)
I don't understand why i have this message, can u help me ?
........................................................

can you provide you spring boot version as I can help you to configure swagger.
BTW you can check my git code for spring boot swagger - how I have configured.. https://github.com/s4sunnny/spring-boot-jwt-authentication
probably I think you haven't added the swagger configuration class and api/link in the security config class.
you can try the below code in your security config file if you want
this code is for security config class
@Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/swagger-ui/*").antMatchers("/swagger-ui/index.html")
                .antMatchers("/swagger-resources/*").antMatchers("/v3/api-docs/*").antMatchers("/swagger-ui.html")
                .antMatchers("/webjars/swagger-ui/*").antMatchers("/configuration/ui").antMatchers("/configuration/**")
                .antMatchers("/webjars/**").antMatchers("/api/auth/**");
    }

you can add or remove the antmatchers link according to you.
below code is for swagger config class
@Configuration
public class SpringDocOpenApiConfig {

    @Bean
    public GroupedOpenApi userApi() {
        return GroupedOpenApi.builder().group("user").pathsToMatch("/user/**").build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public OpenAPI customOpenAPI() {
        return new OpenAPI()
                .components(new Components().addSecuritySchemes("bearer-jwt",
                        new SecurityScheme().type(SecurityScheme.Type.HTTP).scheme("bearer").bearerFormat("JWT")
                                .in(SecurityScheme.In.HEADER).name("Authorization")))
                .info(new Info().title("swagger API").version("Beta"))
                .addSecurityItem(new SecurityRequirement().addList("bearer-jwt", Arrays.asList("read", "write")));
    }

    @Bean
    ForwardedHeaderFilter forwardedHeaderFilter() {
        return new ForwardedHeaderFilter();
    }
}

the above code works with spring version 2.6+
if this doesn't help do let me know with your spring boot version.

I think your project is Spring Mvc Project
I think add more code in SwaggerConfig
As Follows:
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

    registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
        .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");

    registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
        .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resoucres/webjars/");
}

